# Facebook API get new event big picture

Tags: facebook, api, image

I noticed that facebook now allows to set a cover picture also for events, but I seem not able to retrieve that by API anymore.

Example: http://www.facebook.com/events/160889490733938/

Calling the id/picture of that event from the graph api explorer, I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yE/r/tKlGLd_GmXe.png", 
    "is_silhouette": true
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This new picture is called `pic_cover` in the [FQL event table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) <del>– but in my tests it returns always `null`.</del>

There is a padlock sign in the docs that indicates this field may only be read by certain apps, but no further explanation.

<del>And there is no corresponding thing in the API event docs yet.</del>

<del>I think since this is a new feature, we’ll have to wait some time until Facebook will reflect this change in the API as well. Maybe opening a bug report (or joining an existing one) could help to speed this up.</del>

**Update:**

Seems like now it is possible to get the cover picture for an event – both FQL `pic_cover` and `cover` on the API (has to be requested via `fields` parameter) return the image I set as cover image for an event.

(And it also does not seem to be accessible only to owner, as another answer suggested – for a public event I get it even though I am not the creator.)

Docs for API `event` do not seem to be updated yet, no mention of the `cover` field as of now.

Comment: It's also only accessible if you request the `user_photos` permission it seems, quite counter-intuitive. Relevant facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/214434155366227

Comment: I had to request the user_groups permission to pull the photo on my test account.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I believe that the problem is (for now) that the pic_cover belongs to the event creator or uploader, and not to the event itself, so it would require additional permissions in order to get it.

I still didn't find the solution, but I thought this might help in resolving the issue.

Comment: For a public event, I am able to get the FQL `pic_cover` even when I am not the event creator.

Comment: Can you confirm that for all public events? I'm only able to get the picture if the uploader is my friend (when I turn on user_photos in permissions).